# Sequelize many-to-many: recognise lower camelCase alias and instead try upper CamelCase?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am not able to query a many-to-many-association with Sequelize, and I speculate that it's related to a lower/uppercase-issue.

My alias and column name is *camelCase* (`extraId`), but the generated query seems to try *TitleCased* (`ExtraId`), but this is inferred from the error message below.

---

I want to query all `Products` with their associated list of `Extras`, and I try to do that as following:

```
    const data = await models.Product.findAll(
      {
        include: [{
          model: models.Extra,
          as: 'extras'
        }]
      }
    );
```

However, that gives the me the following error:

> `column extras->ProductExtras.ExtraId does not exist`

I have three tables, `Products`, `Extras`, and their association table `ProductExtras` defined as following:

```
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {});
  Product.associate = function(models) {
    Product.belongsToMany(models.Extra, {
      as: 'extras',
      through: 'ProductExtras'
    });
  };



  const Extra = sequelize.define('Extra', {
    code: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    desc: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Extra.associate = function(models) {
    Extra.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
      as: 'products',
      through: 'ProductExtras'
    })
  };



  const ProductExtras = sequelize.define('ProductExtras', {
    productId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    extraId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  ProductExtras.associate = function(models) {
    ProductExtras.belongsTo(models.Product, {foreignKey: 'productId'});
    ProductExtras.belongsTo(models.Extra, {foreignKey: 'extraId'})
  };
```

Any insights or solution to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a foreign key to the belongsToMany, as shown below?  That's what I use to override the default column name for a join-table.

```
Product.associate = function(models) {
    Product.belongsToMany(models.Extra, 
      {
      as: 'extras',
      through: 'ProductExtras',
      foreignKey : 'extraId'
      }
);
```